Grease pencil Issues
Does anyone know how to fix this? When drawing on an object with Grease Pencil and I go to render it, the drawing on the other side shows through?

I solved it in the end. You just go to 'View Layer', just below 'Output Properties' on the top right and click the box that says 'Z'.

Sure, that's why we closed this question as duplicate, because that's the solution given on the other question.
